# mySql and PHP syntax.. something simple is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I am almost embarrassed to ask this, but I have been staring at it and feel like there is an easy answer but i'm not seeing/finding it.

I have this line in my php where i am using a string "checked" to check a checkbox.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ".$row["Chk"].">
```

I am trying to convert so that I can make it more powerful.. e.g. use a 1 or 0 to affect multiple things vs just checking the checkbox.  I have tried changing it to this, but there is clearly a syntax issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ".$row["Chk"].==1 ? "checked" : "" ">
```

this is all being echo'd in a greater statement...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr class=''>
<td class='hikesElement'>
    <form action='checkbox.php' method='post'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ".$row["Chk"].">
    </form>
</td>
</tr>";
}
```

Any thoughts would be great.. kind of new to mySql and php, so much appreciated..

Comment: You have to put parenthesis around the ternary operator (the whole thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss a dot before **">** and some brackets:

```
  <input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ".($row["Chk"]==1 ? "checked" : ""). ">
```

Comment: This was it!  Thanks..
I had used the brackets but forgot to move the dot from after the ] bracket after Chk to the end of the statement.. Wow that one had me..Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See the line

```
<input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ". {$row["Chk"] == 1 ? "checked" : "" } . ">
```

your code must be this:

```
<?php

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr class=''>
<td class='hikesElement'>
    <form action='checkbox.php' method='post'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='hikeL[]' id=".$row["ID"]." ". {$row["Chk"] == 1 ? "checked" : "" } . ">
    </form>
</td>
</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have ID in any type of quotations.

also i'm assuming the `$row["Chk"]` value should be equalt to nothing if not checked or checked="checked" if you want it checked.

```
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```